# MS Access SQL Query with condtional statement

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I am trying to update a table using values from a mapping table. I think its an UPDATE and SELECT statement but I cant figure out how to handle conditions. This is in VBA Access.

I have two tables with following fields:

```
mainTable: [column1],[column2],[xcode],[ycode]
mapTable: [xcode],[ycode],[mapping]
```

I need to do a mapping from mapTable but it has the following condition

```
If mainTable.[column1] = "000" or mainTable.[column1] = "001" Then
  mainTable.[column2] = mapTable.[mapping]
  WHERE mapTable.[xcode] = mainTable.[xcode] 
  AND mapTable.[ycode] = mainTable.[ycode]
Else
  mainTable.[column2] = mapTable.[mapping]
  WHERE mapTable.[xcode] = mainTable.[xcode] 
End If
```

Is there a way to capture this in a single SQL query?

Comment: You may have some issues with this idea.  For instance, if your mapping table has (xcode, ycode, mapping) values of (1,1, "MAP1") and (1,2, "MAP2") and you have a record in the mainTable that contains xcode 1, but Column1 is NOT 000 or 001, then the mainTable would be updated with EITHER "MAP1" or "MAP2", and I'm not sure which one.  You might want to make sure these tables are defined appropriately.

Comment: You *could* do it in 1 query, but as zedfoxus suggests, it'd be a lot better and more intuitive in 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need two queries and that's a good thing: one query gets you the results that you would get with `if` and the other query gives you the results that you would get with `else`.

Query1:

```
update maintable m inner join maptable map on m.xcode = map.xcode and m.ycode = map.ycode
set m.column2 = map.mapping
where m.column1  = "000" or m.column1 = "001"
```

Query2:

```
update maintable m inner join maptable map on m.xcode = map.xcode
set m.column2 = map.mapping
where NOT (m.column1  = "000" or m.column1 = "001")
```